# Android - Expanded Notifications - How to start compressed?

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications

How do I have an expandable notification start in it's compressed state?
I'm sure its a simple value, but I cant find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that happens automatically, and is controlled by the system (depending on how many notifications are already showing, etc).

I am not sure about this, but I notice my BigNotifitions come up compressed by default (unless there are only 1 or 2 other notifications being displayed).

Comment: That's correct: the topmost (highest-priority, most-recent) notification is automatically expanded by the system for the user's convenience. If it can't be expanded, it's left alone, but the auto-expansion does not cascade down to the next notification or anything.

Comment: @Booger  On the flip-side, how do I make a notification start expanded automatically??

Comment: Notifications only expand automatically when they are the first in the list.  So, you can't control that (other than make yours the last notification sent to the device).